# Is it possible to set a local repository as remote repository in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

I have the following scheme:
[image: The image shows how the machines, the Visual Studio installations and the repos are connected]

What I need is to set the FolderHost as the remote repository for my VisualStudio 2013 in my VM. At the same time, FolderHost is the folder where I keep my local repository handled by my Visual Studio 2019.
I don't need to push any changes from VS2013 to FolderHost, I just need to checkout branches. A solution where I need to checkout a branch with VS 2019 to Folder host in order to check it out with VS2013, could also be helpful, but I don't think it is needed.

I think git allows me to do this, but I don't know if I can do it directly with VS2013.

I know there are different alternatives, but there are a couple of reasons why I need to do it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: configure host machine to have a shared folder/drive with VM, then put FolderHost there. Then set git remote via command line in VM (e.g.: ```git remote add origin E:/aaa/bbb/ccc```). Then in HostMachine inside FolderHost run ```git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead```. Then push/pull via visual studio in VM

Comment: The communication between VM and host is not an issue.
In the case I did it as you mention, how do I tell VisualStudio 2013 that its remote repository is FolderHost, on my host? I don't see the "remote" section in Visual Studio, it is empty.

Comment: do it via command line (e.g.: git bash)

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it using Visual Studio, that's why I posted the question

Comment: you only need to do it (git add origin ....) via command line once, after that you can do pull/push via visual studio

Comment: To avoid getting answers that say "use the Git command line", don't use the [tag:git] tag. I took it out, maybe that will help. :-)